# How to do custom x-axis ticks in a Recharts graph

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'd like to put more than one line in the x-axis ticks in a bar chart, something like this:

[image]

But all the props I have to control what renders there, underneath each group of bars, is the `dataKey`, so all I can get with Recharts is:

[image]

This is just rendering one value from my data.

Ideally I'd like to be able to pass `XAxis` a prop to render this  such as:

```
<XAxis dataKey="name" render={(value, dataPoint) => (
  <CustomXAxisName>
    <p>{value}</p>
    <p>{dataPoint.total} Principals</p>
  </CustomXAxisName>
)} />
```

but I can find no affordances for this. There is a more flexible prop to configure `label`, but that refers to one label for the whole axis.

Is there anyway to get this? I'm quite surprised that I can't find a natural way to do this, since Rechart since so flexible in other regards and I don't think this is such a weird idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomizedLabelLineChart?
It shows how to put something diagonally in the x-axis, surely it can be used to put multiple lines.

It uses the `tick={<CustomTick/>}` prop to the `XAxis` component.

Comment: I didn't have the correct terminology and missed this one. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like:

```js
  const customizedGroupTick = (props: any) => {
    const { index, x, y, payload } = props;
  

    return (
      <g>
        <g>
          <text x={x} y={y}>
           data
          </text>
          <text x={x} y={y }>
          data
          </text>
        </g>
      </g>
    );
  };
```

and then

```
 <XAxis
          dataKey="Date"
          axisLine={false}
          tickLine={false}
          scale="band"
          tick={customizedGroupTick}
          interval={0}
        />
```

Comment: Is there a way to know the prop names available without reading the documentation? When I look into the ReChart types, I arrive at `((props: any) => ReactElement<SVGElement>)`. So I can't really deduct from the type which properties are available. Do you have any idea if there are other ways to deducted from the code?